# jquery list specific pages in current page's directory

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to list specific existing pages in current page's directory or even parent directory ?. 
For example i have index.html, index2.html and index3.html and more, more... and I want to have all index* files listed in my *js file and then load them via ajax.

Comment: Try posting an example of what you have tried. No one is going to do your job for you.

Comment: If you have them listed in a js file, the answer is yes.

Comment: @Austin I'm just asking if that is possible? what can i try? - use all index* combinations and check if there is some content ? it's useless. Just don't have any idea. It really needs lots of code? if you say that i want someone to dob job for me ?!?! I am thinking maybe it one line of code that i cannot find .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with client-side code, like JavaScript.  You can only do this with server-side code, such as PHP, ASP/ASPX etc..

Comment: Hmm, but with JS I have ajax so I can load some pages, why i cannot check if they exist ?

Comment: You *can* do that.  But are you suggesting that you want to get a list of all files, or just check for specific filenames?  If you've got a set list of filename that never changes then you can simply try to load them and get a success or fail.  If you're saying "all files in this directory" then you can't do it.

Comment: I would like to check for specific filenames for example beginning with "index" like index1,index2,indexa,indexb, when I don't know which actually will be existing while script executing... only know that begin with "index"

Comment: You would need to check for all possible variations, like a brute-force method.  You'd need to check index0, index1, index2 etc - up to index9, and then indexa - indexz.  Is it possible that there will be others, or will it just be those 36?

Comment: yeah there can be everything! - it's really `index*` so brute-force rather is wrong idea :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  In that case we're back to my original answer, no - you cannot do it.  You would need to write a server-side script that gets a list of the files as it's not possible to do that from the client machine, where JavaScript runs.  What server script languages can you run?

Comment: None, it's some wikimedia plugin so I even dont have access to server ;) I'll have to change my approach . Thanks for answer.

Comment: No problem.  Sorry it couldn't be the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that using **[SAMMY](http://sammyjs.org/)** few projects ago... I don't know if it could help you...